# Returning a Nullable Bool from Converter to XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a group of three Radio Buttons bound to a nullable bool. I have the converters written, but I'm not sure how to write the ConvertBack? When I open the window, multiple options of the group are selected.

Converter class:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    switch ((string)parameter)
    {
        case "Pass":
            return true;
        case "Fail":
            return false;
        case "NotComplete":
            return null;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    switch ((bool?)value)
    {
        case true:
            return "Pass";
        case false:
            return "Fail";
        case null:
            return "NotComplete";
        default:
            return "NotComplete";
    }
}
```

RadioButtons in XAML:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="GroupOneRadioButton" IsEnabled="{Binding CanPassGroupOneTest}" IsChecked="{Binding GroupOneTestResult, Converter={StaticResource radioButtonConverter}, ConverterParameter=Pass}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<RadioButton GroupName="GroupOneRadioButton" IsEnabled="{Binding CanPassGroupOneTest}" IsChecked="{Binding GroupOneTestResult, Converter={StaticResource radioButtonConverter}, ConverterParameter=Fail}"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<RadioButton GroupName="GroupOneRadioButton" IsEnabled="{Binding CanPassGroupOneTest}" IsChecked="{Binding GroupOneTestResult, Converter={StaticResource radioButtonConverter}, ConverterParameter=NotComplete}"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

More details:

Apologies for being unclear at the beginning. Hopefully this explains:

- GroupOneTestResult is a Nullable boolean, defined as:

  `public bool? GroupOneTestResult { get; set; }`
- In the XAML are three radio buttons - Pass, Failed, Not Complete, which as a group I want to bind to GroupOneTestResult (button one, pass, binds to True. Button two, fail, binds to false. Button three, Not Complete, binds to null)
- When the button in the group is clicked in the XAML, the correct value needs to be stored in GroupOneTestResult
- GroupOneTestResult needs to be changed programatically (for example, when a test result is loaded) and this value being reflected by the automatically selected RadioButton.
- I have the Converter class which, in my first attempt, would take ConverterParameter from the XAML and get the correct boolean value. This is not working. I'm not sure how to do the above.

Comment: The Convert method is not at all converting the value of the source property of the Binding. Assuming that `GroupOneTestResult` returns the appropriate string, change `switch ((string)parameter)` to `switch ((string)value)`. And remove the ConverterParameter setting from all Bindings.

Comment: Do I have this wrong then? I'd like the bool to be True, False, or Null, based on the radio button selected being Passed, Failed, or Not Completed respectively. However some code in the ViewModel needs to be able to update the radio buttons too (so if a result is loaded, for example, the correct radio button is selected)

Comment: Sorry if I have the wrong idea; I'm still fairly new to this

Comment: As said, if the `GroupOneTestResult` property would return those strings (we don't know because you didn't tell us), then the Convert method should switch on `value`, not `parameter`, and there shouldn't be a ConverterParameter at all. And ConvertBack should just work.

Comment: But there's no indication of which radio button to highlight for which result?

Comment: Sorry, your question needs more detail. What exactly is the GroupOneTestResult property? How is it declared? What are the RadioButton supposed to do?

Comment: @Clemens I've added some more detail to the question. Any other queries let me know

Comment: I think you are confusing `MulitiBinding` with `Converter` and `ConverterParameter`. `Converter` is meant to be used for types which does not suit binding to the `DependencyProperty`. Let's say you wanted to bind `IsChecked` property of `RadioButton` to `int`, then you would need a `Converter` to convert your `integers` to `booleans`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding multiple RadioButtons in a group to a single property requires special handling in the Binding Converter.

The ConvertBack method should only return a value when a RadioButton was checked, to avoid that automatic unchecking of the others will have any further effect.

Besides that, the Convert method must compare the passed `value` to the three possible values according to the `parameter` string.

```
public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    switch ((string)parameter)
    {
        case "Pass":
            return (bool?)value == true;
        case "Fail":
            return (bool?)value == false;
        default:
            return (bool?)value == null;
    }
}

public object ConvertBack(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if ((bool)value)
    {
        switch ((string)parameter)
        {
            case "Pass":
                return (bool?)true;
            case "Fail":
                return (bool?)false;
            default:
                return (bool?)null;
         }
    }

    return Binding.DoNothing;
}
```